# wp-cli only displays PHP version for all input options

Tags: wp-cli

I see the same output regardless which input parameters I pass to wp-cli.

```
[tosh@server94]$ wp-cli.phar --info
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.36
Content-type: text/html

[tosh@server94]$ wp-cli.phar help cache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.36
Content-type: text/html
```

What is going on?

**Update in response to Answer**

There seems to be 2 PHP "installations" on my host's server. None of them works, it seems. The first one, with cgi, has the above symptoms. The second one, cli version, outputs nothing.

```
[userx@server921 jack]$ /usr/bin/php wp-cli.phar --info
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.33
Content-type: text/html

[userx@server921 jack]$ /usr/bin/php -v
PHP 5.5.33 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Mar  3 2016 10:03:52)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v5.1.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2014, by Zend Technologies
    with Suhosin v0.9.37.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2014, by SektionEins GmbH
[userx@server921 jack]$ php -v
PHP 5.5.33 (cli) (built: Mar  3 2016 10:03:51)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v5.1.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2014, by Zend Technologies
    with Suhosin v0.9.37.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2014, by SektionEins GmbH
[userx@server921 jack]$ php wp-cli.phar --info
[userx@server921 jack]$
```

Answer (score 3):

Try running `php wp-cli.phar`

**EDIT**

It looks a little like `php` on your system isn't setup to use `php-cli` (it's using `php-cgi` instead):

try running: `php -v`

on my machine I get:

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2015 01:34:46) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

The important bit is where it says **`(cli)`** - this means it's the cli, and not cgi version.

Comment: if you think that is the problem (and you are probably right) just write it as an answer ;) the world will not come to an end if the answer will be wrong

Comment: Thanks @MarkKaplun - I've updated it with extra info now too!

Comment: @DavidKemp Please see update in the Question above.